# Asp-Classic ADODB Recordset missing Records

Tags: database, asp-classic, recordset

one of the simplest Components in my website just stopped working from one day to the other without any changes in Code.

```
'Connection Declaration as connection
Set rs = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.Open "SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY id DESC", connection, 1, 3
while not rs.EOF
  'writing some Table from the records in DB
  'Simplified Code %>
  <tr><td><%=rs("id")%></td><td><%=rs("description")&></td></tr>
  <%
  rs.MoveNext
Wend
```

in my Database i have verified the extraordinary number of 30 records :(

when above code is executed i see 2 of them

This tells me two things,

> first: the tablename is Correct and the connection to the Database is established
>   second: the table-generation in itself is correct

I also have a smaller Testing-System. there the exact same code on a sample Database produces the expected Results.

Unfortunately i have no means of "instant-access" to my main page for "debugging purposes"

Is there any known Bugs for ADODB Recordsets losing records? Please keep in mind the Code is exactly the same and working "error-free".

Comment: What's the purpose of `connection, 1, 3` at the end of your query?

Comment: that is not the query anymore it is the definition for connection and cursors. you could also do this: rs.Connection = connection 
rs.Cursors = 1,3
rs.open(query)

Comment: If your code works with a different database then the error is more likely to be in the database than the asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few suggestions.

Use Option Explicit if not already - (I didn't see it in your code) this will display SQL errors, so that may help.

Check that you haven't destroyed RS.

Also, "connection, 1, 3" means 'active connection', 'cursortype', 'locktype'

Your cursortype is 'adOpenKeySet' - 3 or 'adOpenStatic' is better, unless you specifically want a KeySet? try calling the Open this way to force the defaults (which oddly enough are 3 and 1 respectively !) :

```
RS.Open "SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY id DESC",connection
```

I also usually write RS output loops like this :

```
If Not RS.BOF Then
   ' write table tag HTML
   Do While Not RS.EOF
      ' write table row + row data
      RS.MoveNext
   Loop
   ' write end table tag HTML
Else
   ' write "RS is empty!"
End If
```

This will make it easier to tell if recordset is empty or not.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. i was on vacation for a month, so my coworker was having his try on it and found a small difference in the environments which caused the error. just because you were wondering, the `connection, 1, 3` is our "coding standard" (which we do not have but nvm). In the end the error was found in some missing folders used inside the table (well if they had been there). my co-worker fixed this so i am just gonna accept your answer